# Create User Defined Number of Inputs for Website

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

I am trying to make a website that accepts multiple inputs based on how many the user wants to enter. Lets say they want to enter 4 addresses. I want to be able to handle that input but also if they ask for 10 inputs without having to create pages for each instance. I am new to programming so any insight would be great. Also, I saw some examples of website that I believe use javascript to take in input, create more fields, and process the data without having to switch pages. How would I implement such a thing and would I have to change my data sourcing from php in anyway if I did? Thanks!

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html class="no-js" lang="en">
      <head>
          <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script>
            $(function(){
                var c = 0;

                $("#button1").click(function(){
                  c = $("#inputs").val();

                  $("#mydiv").html("");

                  for(i=0;i<c;i++){
                        $("#mydiv").append('<input type="text" id="data'+i+'" name="data'+i+'" /><br/>');
                  }
                });

                $("#button2").click(function(){
                    $.post("file.php",$("#form1").serialize(),function(data){
                        alert(data);
                    });
                });

            });
          </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <form id="form1">
          Type the number of inputs:
          <input type="text" id="inputs" name="inputs" />
          <input type="button" id="button1" value="Create" />
          <div id="mydiv"></div>
          <input type="button" id ="button2" value="Send" />
        </form>

        </body>
    </html>
```

If you need to process the new inputs with PHP:

file.php

```
    <?php
      for( $i=0; $i<$_POST["inputs"] ; $i++){
        echo $_POST["data".$i]."\n";
      }
    ?>
```

Comment: [Run the sample](http://runnable.com/Uz-Y4biGW841ZsnE/dynamically-inputs-for-php)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for this

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/dynamic-add-textbox-input-button-radio-element-html-javascript/

Comment: Not necessarily. Lets say I have just one text field with a submit button. They put in the first input then click submit. The web page stores that input then clears the field allowing them to input another if they wish. If they eventually decide they have enough, I will have another button that passes all the data that they inputted  into a PHP call to get the results from google maps. I hope that helps but any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Then you can do like::  when user input something get those inputs one by one and put those inputs into session variables. Once they are done with inputting then pass those inputs for further processing. Once you are done with the further processing then you destroy those session variables.